# How to save multiple web pages as pdf files or screenshot using excel macro?

Tags: html, excel, vba, google-chrome, web-scraping

I tried out the code below but its only saving the page's HTML content and ends up excluding most of the important content on the page.

If anyone can help me on how to save these webpages as pdf or a png file it would be great.

```
Sub SaveWebpage()
    Dim objHTTP As Object, _
        objFSO As Object, _
        objFil As Object, _
        lngRow As Long, _
        strURL As String, _
        strPath As String, _
        strFilename As String
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'On the next line change the file path as desired.  Make sure the path ends with \
    strPath = "C:\Users\Pradyumna\Desktop\Save Webpages"
    For lngRow = 2 To Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        strFilename = strPath & lngRow & ".htm"
        strURL = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value
        objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
        objHTTP.send ""
        Set objFil = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFilename)
        objFil.Write objHTTP.responseText
        objFil.Close
    Next
    Set objHTTP = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objFil = Nothing
    MsgBox "All done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at puppeteer.

Comment: Also you may try to automate IE to open webpage and save it as .mht or .html  file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may save a webpage as PDF simply [using headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) via command line:

```vb
lRet = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"" --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=""C:\Test\Sample.pdf"" https://api.myip.com", 1, True)
MsgBox "Ret code: " & lRet
```

You need to specify the actual path to your Chrome, and to the PDF file to be saved. Note, you need Chrome version 60 or higher to run the code on Windows.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me which platform are you using to run this?

Comment: @PradyumnaMudholkar That code should be run as VBA macro or WSH VBScript.

Comment: Here is [the VBS code example](http://forum.script-coding.com/viewtopic.php?pid=129907#p129907) which facilitates Chrome detection (ends up with chrome.exe path and version), it can be adopted in VBA without much effort.