# Take screenshot of webpage and save it as jpg

Tags: excel, vba

How to take print screen of whole page in jpg using Excel vba?

Weblink=https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-10000&symbol=NIFTY&symbol=NIFTY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17

```
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Dim frm As Variant
    Dim element, submitInput As Variant
    Dim rowCollection, htmlRow As Variant
    Dim rowSubContent, rowSubData As Variant
    Dim anchorRange As Range, cellRng As Range
    Dim start
    Dim A As String
    Dim hTable As HTMLTable
    Dim clipboard As Object

    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-10000&symbol=NIFTY&symbol=NIFTY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17"

    While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save multiple web pages as pdf files or screenshot using excel macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52379304/how-to-save-multiple-web-pages-as-pdf-files-or-screenshot-using-excel-macro)

Comment: You may try to implement data webscraping via API like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53774575/2165759)